# Nuxt require() dynamic images - cannot find module

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

I am trying to get Nuxt/image to work with dynamic images. As per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970096/nuxt-displaying-images-using-markdown-it-relative-to-markdown-content/70975050#70975050) I am requiring the image. However, on generating a static site I am getting *"Cannot find module"* errors for every image. I tried every possible way to create the path I could come up with.

My folder structure is like this:

```
nuxt-project/content/projects/project1/project1.md
nuxt-project/content/projects/project1/image1.jpg
nuxt-project/content/projects/project1/image2.jpg
```

I tried generating the path like this

```
pathForImage(filename) {
    return "~/content/projects/" + this.project.id + "/" + filename;
}
```

also

```
return "./content/projects/" + this.project.id + "/" + filename;

return "../content/projects/" + this.project.id + "/" + filename;
```

But everything results in

```
Error: Cannot find module './content/projects/project1/project1.jpg'
    at webpackEmptyContext (webpack:/components/global sync:2:0)
```

or

```
Error: Cannot find module '../content/projects/project1/project1.jpg'
```

or

```
Error: Cannot find module '~/content/projects/project1/project1.jpg'
```

The file exists of course. I also tried using the static directory in case the problem lays with using the content directory, but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
pathForImage(filename) {
    return require("~/content/projects/" + this.project.id + "/" + filename)
}
```

you should use "require"